# I need to identify this connector from inside a hot tub control panel

Tags: connector

A mouse chewed through the wire of our hot tub control panel and I need to replace this five pin connector. It is 1.3mm wide.

[image: connector]

Comment: Please document the size (both dimensions)of the connector including pitch between pins

Comment: "It is 1.3mm wide." Yeah, right. And I am 16 cm tall.

Comment: the red wire is probably about 1.3 mm in diameter

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a TE,  Economy Power 2.5mm 1 row, [Part number 1969442-5](https://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1969442-5.html).

[image: TE 1969442-5]

{Digikey}

You can get it here: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/1969442-5/4021406

I found it with my [Identiconn connector identifier utility](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=propr_rect_conn_2p5&s=Economy%20Power%202.5%201r).

Comment: To the asker and posterity: Note that the housing all by itself won't do you any good unless you also have either some pre-crimped leads, or the contacts and a way to crimp them. (It looks like the official crimp tool costs $572, which I assume you don't want to spend.)